# Converting imagemagick command line to Wand (python)- printing deskew

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I am having trouble converting the following command-line to Wand.

`convert img.png -deskew 80% -print "%[deskew:angle]" null:`

I was able to locate the deskew method in Wand but I want to store the amount of deskew.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [Image.artifacts](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image.artifacts) dict.

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    img.deskew(0.8 * img.quantum_range)  # 80%
    angle = float(img.artifacts['deskew:angle'])
```